# Spam sites are using snippets of our content for the meta descriptions repeatedly for a whole host of sites

Tags: spam, meta-description

I work for a doctor who has several large information websites on health, diet, breast cancer and lung cancer, to name but a few.

The problem is that almost every post on every site has had every couple of sentences copied and used as a meta description for websites that all lead to a sales/porn or spam sites.

So if I use SEO plagiarism checker (http://smallseotools.com/plagiarism-checker/)  the whole post comes up as plagiarized.  When I click on a plagiarized snippet taken from the original content of the post like the one below the Google search results look like:-

---

Lose weight extremely fast unhealthy Order immediately
losefat.hoseandfitting
There is a host of information on weight loss out there, most of which has no scientific basis such as fad diets, weight loss pills, weight-loss supplements and ...

How fast can i lose weight low carb 100% All natural
loseweight.hoseandfitting5
There is a host of information on weight loss out there, most of which has no scientific basis such as fad diets, weight loss pills, weight-loss supplements and ...

How to lose weight super fast in - fastclub.us
fastclub.us/.html
There is a host of information on weight loss out there, most of which has no scientific basis such as fad diets, weight loss pills, weight-loss supplements and ...

---

These links all lead to sales sites, spam, sometimes porn, competition and sometimes what appears to be malware.

This problem affects almost every sentence on some of the posts and also seems to be across all the websites - several have been de indexed by Google.
The problem is these sites are not linking to our main sites just taking every snippet of content and using it as a meta description repeatedly.  Is this going to be a huge problem?  The copyscape plagiarism checker passes our original posts and does not come up with the same problem.

Any ideas on what to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: File a DCMA complaint per site with Google and explain the situation as completely and succinctly as possible. You may want to write that part up before hand so that you can work it into perfection. How your site performs in SEs are your only real concern. Next, find a solution to scraping. Once a spammer decides that your content does well for spamming, the come to your site like cockroaches and make your life a nightmare. However, if they have trouble scraping your site, then they stay away just as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Scraper sites like this won't usually hurt your site's SEO:

- Google is pretty good about knowing which site should get credit for content.   Your site should get indexed and the scraper sites should't.
- Google is pretty good about identifying and not indexing spam sites.
- Meta descriptions don't get indexed. They may show up in the search results as the site snippet, but Google doesn't make the words in them searchable.   To be searchable, the words would also have to appear in the page.

You shouldn't have to worry about this problem.   The only reason you would need to do something would be if those sites were actually showing up instead of yours when somebody searches for something.  It doesn't sound likely to me that it would ever happen.

If that does happen, you could [report the spam to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93713?hl=en) and [request that Google remove the copied content from their search engine](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en).